# Where can I learn more about C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-manual

I would like to learn more about C++0x. What are some good references and resources? Has anyone written a good book on the subject yet?

Comment: Was -2 before the comment, now +5? People must be fickle - it's essentially the same question!

Comment: what comment do you talk about

Comment: @litb   he is telling abt up votes for the qn.initially it was -2 afterwards it is 5 now 17

Comment: @litb I think mark is talking about the edit he made to the post. The original question was just "Best place to learn c++ 0X features?"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Articles on

[Lambda Expressions](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=254),

[The Type Traits Library](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=276),

[The rvalue Reference](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=310),

[Concepts](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=313),

[Variadic Templates](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=396),

[shared_ptr](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=239)

[Regular Expressions](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/185300414)

[Tuples](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401974)

[Multi Threading](http://www.informit.com/guides/printerfriendly.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=414)

### General Discussion

[The C/C++ Users Journal](http://www.petebecker.com/newlib1.html),

[The New C++](http://www.petebecker.com/newlib.html),

[Article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/cpp0x.html)

### Videos

[Google tech talk](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2768126766555555011)

### overview of various features

[overview at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x)

### Library

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/)

Comment: The informit articles are nice for an overview. But keep in mind that most of them are dated (for example, the rvalue reference article doesn't reflect the rule change from almost 2 years ago) and that the author is known to have written at least one bad C++ book where he demonstrates that he doesn't always know what he's talking about (see accu.org book reviews). For an accurate view of rvalue references, I can recommend David Abraham's article series: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: Concepts aren't part of c++0x anymore

Answer (score 36):

- [ISO C++ committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)
- [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.research.att.com/~bs)

  - Especially his [C++0x FAQ](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html)
  - [*The Design of C++0x* (pdf)](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/rules.pdf) from C/C++ Users Journal, May 2005
- Wikipedia's [C++0x article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x)
- G++'s [experimental support for C++0x](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) with the -std=c++0x switch
- SO's [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) tag

Comment: You have two identical links in the line "Bjarne Stroustrup's web site. (See also his article in C++ User's Journal)". Otherwise your reply is better than the one I have provided (more informative) and I will by voting it up once you fix this.

Answer (score 17):

[Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com)'s blog, He posts new developments in C++0x and links to detailed references

[Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/)'s Website

Both are ISO-C++ standards committee members. Herb Sutter will posts an update on each meeting that he attends.

[Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2798.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia article seems like an excellent starting point: [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x)

It provides a good summary with brief examples and is updated regularly to match latest additions.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two videos on the subject. They are a bit old, but still very relevant:
New Features in the Next C++ Standard ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAG5txfYnW4 ) and [Advanced Topics in Programming Languages Series: C++ Threads](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=3528799355371049884)

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of stuff on this very site - some of the posts include very informative discussion.  I would point you to Google but it's going to be more efficient to search in [C++0x tagged posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) here imo.

Here's [a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645326/new-version-of-c) to start with, which includes indirection to [Stroustrup's own summary](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html).  Scott Meyers has presentation materials on the topic [here](http://www.artima.com/shop/overview_of_the_new_cpp).

Check up on your favourite compiler's support for the new version.  Microsoft VC10 support is summarized [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx).  GCC info can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Official state of the standard for the language is available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/).  Evolution of the language is in many places tied to ongoing work in Boost.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193605/which-boost-libraries-are-heading-for-tr2) for some info on that.

Honestly my preference these days is to look here for 99% of needed info rather than resort to a book.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer [Presentation Materials: Overview of the New C++ (C++0x)](http://www.artima.com/shop/overview_of_the_new_cpp) by Scott Meyers.