# Which boost libraries are heading for TR2?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++-tr2

If found this quote at boost.org:

> [More Boost libraries are in the pipeline for TR2](http://www.boost.org/users/)

It links to the [TR2 call from proposals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1810.html).  But I can't seem to find any other information on which boost libraries are headed for TR2.

I've seen a draft proposal for Boost.Asio, and I vaguely remember seeing something about Boost.System and Boost.Filesystem being proposed as well.

- Which boost libraries are headed for TR2?
- What else has been proposed for the TR2?
- Are there any good sources of information for this?

I know everyone's really focused on C++0x right now, and don't expect to find a lot of official information.  But surely someone's documented something about the TR2.

Comment: You did see the date on that document? It was 2005-04-29. Nothing is headed for TR2 (and TR1 was never accepted) - the next milestone is getting C++0x ratified.

Comment: This cannot be answered with any degree of certitude since the committee is free to drop anything anytime.

Comment: Maybe we should change this into "Which Boost libraries SHOULD BE heading for TR2?

Comment: So what does 'in the pipeline' mean?.  I don't what's been accepted (as Neil points out nothing has).  I'm curious as to which Boost libraries have their sights set on being part of TR2.  Were there any proposals for the TR2?  Or was the call for proposals ignored in favor of finishing c++0x?

Comment: TR2 is nowadays planned (soon) after C++0x, containing fixes and additions that did not make it into the standard.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but after Neil's slap-in-the-face comment I had to find out for myself and none of the other comments were at all helpful.

Wikipedia doesn't have a [C++ Technical Report 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_2) page but it does have a [tr2 section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Technical_Report_2) in the [C++ Technical Report 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1) page.

Here is a quick list from Wikipedia.

- Boost.Asio
- Signals/Slots, a combination of Boost.Signals and libsigc++
- Boost.Filesystem
- Boost.Any
- boost::lexcal_cast<>
- Boost.String Algo
- Boost.System

There are a couple more as well.  Wikipedia has the links for to the actual proposals.  The latest proposal (something about heterogenious containers) as sent in May 2009, less than a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

No proposal to create a TR2 exists or will exist until C++0x is released.

Comment: umm... http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1810.html.  I guess technically TR2 isn't proposed here, but the call for proposals seems to imply a TR2 is anticipated.

Comment: c++0x and c++tr2 are separate.  TR2 may be functionally dead, but it did not become c++0x.  Many of the tr2 proposals reference features in c++0x.