# new version of c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there going to be a new version of C++ and when?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. When it's ready (current estimate 2011)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The creator of C++ C++0X FAQ:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html

- Question: [When will C++0x be a formal standard?](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#when-standard)

But C++ 0X does exists in some degree in various compilers. See both:

- Question: [When will compilers implement C++0x?](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#when-compilers)
- [GCC C++ 0X support](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

To see what C++ 0X will be like, look at the wiki:
[Wiki C++ 0X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x)

Answer (score 2):

The C++0x is the unofficial name for the new C++ Standard which is intended to replace C++03 standard (published in 2003). The final draft of the international standard is due in March of 2011. However this does not mean you will be able to use the new features straight away as the standards will have to be implemented by compilers and the completeness of these implementations will vary.

You can find a draft of the new standard here:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf

However you can use the Technical Release 1 libraries which include a fair deal of functionality that will appear in the new standard which you can find here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1

If you are looking for the status of the C++ox implementation in GCC (which is a free compiler) see this link:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/cxx0x_status.html

Here is a link to a really detailed FAQ that provides a lot of additional information:

- http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html

Answer (score 0):

However, the experience shows that the complete implementation of a freshly released standard, takes years... If one considers the complexity of the recent additions, I am very pessimistic about getting cross-platform compliant implementations soon.