# What do I need to know about C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I learn more about C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200237/where-can-i-learn-more-about-c0x)

I am fairly familiar with C++03 but I still need to come to terms with C++0x so I would like to read some fairly digestible information on C++0x.

I have looked at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) but I am on the look out for something that is more readable. So is there a book or series of blog entries that provide a nice introduction to the matarial?

Comment: First, you should probably start calling it C++1x, and don't be surprised if you have to call it C++2x before it finally ships. :D

Comment: This would be a good community Wiki q in my opinion.  Nice q.

Comment: @Randolpho: I don't think we will have to wait more than 9 years, but seeing that it's already 2010, "C++1x" seems a safer bet than "C++0x".

Comment: Similar post which could help you with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200237/

Comment: @bdhar actually looks to be an exact duplicate.  That question already has a ton of useful information.

Comment: It's been called C++0x for a long time, and I don't see a reason to change that until we have an actual number, like C++11 or C++12.  C++1x should be reserved for the immediately following version, which (IIRC) some people hope to have out around 2018 or so.

Comment: @wheaties:  Agreed, but the last info on that site is well over a year old, and things have changed since then (the biggie being dropping concepts).  This is still a dupe, but with a potential purpose.  Perhaps doron should have edited the older post to ask, in addition "Has anything changed recently?"

Comment: If only there were a merge ability handed people...

Answer (score 4):

There is a ton of stuff on this very site - some of the posts include very informative discussion.  I would point you to Google but it's going to be more efficient to search in [C++0x tagged posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) here imo.

Here's [a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645326/new-version-of-c) to start with, which includes indirection to [Stroustrup's own summary](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html).  Scott Meyers has presentation materials on the topic [here](http://www.artima.com/shop/overview_of_the_new_cpp).

Check up on your favourite compiler's support for the new version.  Microsoft VC10 support is summarized [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx).  GCC info can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Official state of the standard for the language is available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/).  Evolution of the language is in many places tied to ongoing work in Boost.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193605/which-boost-libraries-are-heading-for-tr2) for some info on that.

Honestly my preference these days is to look here for 99% of needed info rather than resort to a book.

Comment: @sbi - noted, I modified the URL. thx

Answer (score 2):

It's too early for a book. The standard isn't fixed yet.

Now, if you think wikipedia is hard to read, you might try [Stroustrup's page](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html) about it. However it might seem harder to read to some.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good tutorial on [codeproject here for VC++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cpp10.aspx).  Even if you aren't using Visual Studio though it's still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Learn whatever feature you would have loved having in C++98 in the first place. For me, it was variadic templates, lambda functions, decltype and other cool stuff.

If you still don't know what to learn first, maybe you should try to *understand* what issues from the C++98 are adressed. I say this because all the xvalue, move semantics and al stuff is quite heavy to grasp if you don't know what the problems were (and still are btw). This may imply learning some more C++98 first.

Then, you can always browse the Wikipedia article and look at whatever you find cool. Implementors don't provide all the features yet, so you'll look like a 5 year old staring at the front window of a toy store. This is a good reason to behave like one.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked this series of blog posts by the Visual C++ Team Blog:

- [The Future of the C++ Language](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/08/10/the-future-of-the-c-language.aspx)
- [Lambdas, auto, and static_assert: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx)
- [Rvalue References: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx)
- [decltype: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/04/22/decltype-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-3.aspx)

Comment: +1 Sadly, the article on rvalue references is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Overview of the New C++ (C++0x)](http://www.artima.com/shop/overview_of_the_new_cpp) book by Scott Meyers to be a good, detailed summary of the main features. It's more of a presentation with very detailed footnotes that an actual book, but it's still an excellent, short read.

Comment: +1 for tracking down the closest thing to an actual book

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using the [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=book_creator) functionality of Wikipedia to make it more readable/printable. I did the same for the C++0x page.