# C++ standard API

Tags: c++, api

I am a student, and new to C++. I am  searching for a standard C++ API that is as comprehensive as the Java API. So far I have been using [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/), and [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/).

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by an API? What features do you want? What's bad with the standard library?

Comment: Are you looking for a comprehensive reference for the C++ standard library?  Or are you looking for a C++ library that is as comprehensive as the Java library?

Comment: The sites you mentioned cover everything that can be considered C++ API.

Comment: @ james, I am looking for a c++ library that is as comprehensive as the java library.

Comment: There really isn't _one_; you'll probably need to use pieces of several libraries.  What libraries you need to use depends entirely on what functionality you need.

Comment: @Dustin I think the closest thing would be Qt library. http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ and Java have very different standard libraries because they make very different assumptions about what they are going to be used for.

Java assumes that applications or applets will be running on a host with a full featured OS, with a defined way of doing most normal things.

There's a lot of content in that, for instance, in java, the output will be an application or applet.  C++ does not make that assumption, because C++ can be used for building OS Kernels and drivers for kernels, it can be used for programming full stack real time applications on microcontrollers, or processing blocks in supercomputers.

C++ can be used for implementing the very operating system on which it will run.

For these reasons, the standard library assumes almost nothing about what it will have available, and so the standard library doesn't make any dependencies on those features.

The only exception is with files and streaming, because almost any operating system like stack has something that looks like a file stream if it has anything like files at all.

If you want a richer set of OS Specific api's you need to look at something non-standard.  A great choice is the Qt framework, which provides many tools similar to what is found in the Java libraries, is cross platform, and works well with native C++ idioms.

Comment: I agree, I think the standard library, boost, and Qt make for a very comprehensive set of libraries with minimal dependencies and are easy to get up and running (one of my pet peeves... dependency hell).

Answer (score 4):

C++ has a *standard library*.

You can try reading the ["The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215). While I don't own it myself, it's on our [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (which I recommend you check out), so it shouldn't be bad.

Note C++ isn't Java, so the libraries don't necessarily have the same functionality. Another resource you'll want to look at is [Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost/info), which serves as a source for well-written C++ libraries for things the standard library lacks.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU C++ Standard library documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/) is the one I refer to most often.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a virtual machine language and as such attempts to have a comprehensive api to provide a platform independent method of drawing/wrtinging to files / anything.  IN the guts of JRE they are taking these generic inputs and using them to do platform specific things.  In C++ you are the one that does that work.  Many c++ libraries are platform specific see MFC, ATL or code that is written for XWindows it your job to decide how you want to implement a feature and see if that is a platform specific feature or can be done in a platform independent manner.

If you are writing on windows or unix I can assure that the OS API is very complete and will allow you to do what ever your trying to accomplish.  Also take a look at cross platfom libraries like lib qt.

Answer (score 1):

Java's standard library is aimed at providing ready-to-use functionality, while the C++ standard library is aimed at providing building blocks that aren't defined by the core language. The [Boost](http://www.boost.org) library has mainly the same orientation as the standard library (with a few exceptions such as image processing). I think the closest you can get to something like Java's standard library is the [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) library.

However, when I tried on the Poco library I found that it was a bit too C-oriented for my taste.

That is, it's not "modern". You get that impression straight away without even looking at the APIs, because the online docs uses 1990's frames. :-) However, it may fill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the c++ standard library I'd look at [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference). It covers the current standards. After familiarizing yourself with that, you could try looking at [boost](http://www.boost.org).
There are a number of changes in the upcoming c++0x standard. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) has info on a number of these as does [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200237/where-can-i-learn-more-about-c0x).

The number one book, IMO, for c++ is [*Effective C++*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) by Scott Meyers.