# Trouble with the C++ standard

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, standards-compliance

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
>   [Where can I learn more about C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200237/where-can-i-learn-more-about-c0x)

I have been reading the C++ standard from quite some time now, and its making by brain turn.
How much time does one need to get this thing inside your head?

Are their any literatures available [ e.g. some kind of a commentary ] which a normal average human brain can understand?

Or is there some book i can read and keep using C++ standard as a reference which would be a just balance for me? Need the bosses of SO to give some good suggestions.

Comment: Stroustoup's "The C++ Programming Language" is essentially annotated simplified standard...

Comment: @Armen - How is this a duplicate? Do you think i dont know about books? I want to know about something which i can use as a reference in tandem with C++ standard.

Comment: @Lohit - Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language"?

Comment: Why are you suggesting answers and duplicates about specifically C++0x? Just because of the tag?

Comment: @Jason: It's Meyers, not Myers.

Comment: @Lohit: Also, the duplicate I suggested contains "reference-style" books as well

Comment: Well, Herb Sutter did say to wait for the book from Scott Meyers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Bjarne's C++0x FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html)